# Jenkins Allure report is not showing all the results when we have multiple scenarios

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber, allure

I have the following scenario outline and I am generating allure report, But in the report we are not getting all the scenarios data, its showing only last run data.

It is showing only  | uat1_nam | Password01 | test data result

Jenkins plugin version  i am using is 2.13.6

Scenario Outline: Find a transaction based on different criteria and view the details

```
Given I am login to application with user "<user id>" and password "<password>" 

When I navigate to Balances & Statements -> Find a transaction

Then I assert I am on screen Balances & Statements -> Find a transaction -> Find a transaction

@UAT1
Examples: 
  | user id  | password   | 
  | uat1_moz | Password01 | 
  | uat1_nam | Password01 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue.
We are running test with the same software on Linux and Windows, and generating results into 2 separate folders.
Then we have:
allure-reports

|_ linux_report
|_ windows_report

Then we are using the following command in the Jenkinsfile:

```
 allure([
     includeProperties: false,
     jdk: '',
     properties: [],
     reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
     results: [[path: 'allure-reports/linux-report'], [path: 'allure-reports/windows-report']]
 ])
```

Similar to Sarath, only the results of the from the last run are available...
I also tried to run the cli directly on my machine, same results.

```
allure serve allure-reports/linux-report allure-reports/windows-report
```

I already found many methods, actually this one is very similar to my use case, but I do not understand why it works here, and not for me...
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/1051

I also tried with the following method, but the Docker container is not running properly on Linux, due to permission issues... But I am running the container from a folder where I got all permissions. Same results if I give my userID in parameters:
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service#MULTIPLE-PROJECTS---REMOTE-REPORTS

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get deeper into the topic, and I am finally able to prove why the data are overwritten.
I used a very simple example to generate 2 different reports, where only allure.epic was different.

As I thought, if we generate 2 different reports, with the same source folder, but generate 2 separate reports, then only the latest report will be considered (allure.epic name was updated in between).

If I have 2 different folders, with the same code (but only the allure.epic is different), then I have the all data available, and stored in different Suites!

Then, to make sure that allure considers the reports as different, and make a different classification for each OS, we have to make tests on code which is stored in different locations. Which does not fit with my usecase, as the same code is tested on both Linux and Windows.

Or maybe is there an option for pytest-allure to specify the root classification?